# php foreach nested loop retrieve all records

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, nested

```
$json_string = '{
   "response_code": 200,
   "info": {
      "days": [
         {
            "code": "A",
            "runs": "111"
         },
         {
            "code": "B",
            "runs": "222"
         },
         {
            "code": "C",
            "runs": "333"
         }
      ],
      "name": "SUPER MARIO",
      "number": "010203",
      "classes": [
         {
            "points": "6523",
            "name": "ABC",
            "available": "N"
         },
         {
            "points": "4253",
            "name": "XYZ",
            "available": "N"
         },
         {
            "points": "2323",
            "name": "JOHN",
            "available": "N"
         },
         {
            "points": "5236",
            "name": "TAMIL",
            "available": "N"
         }
      ]
   }
}';

$jsondata = $json_string;
$arr = json_decode($jsondata, true);

foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
    echo $k."<br>";
}
```

it prints

**response_code 

info**

But, I need the results like this

**6523 ABC

4253 XYZ

2323 JOHN

5326 TAMIL**

I have tried and achieved this above results using this below code. But, I want to do it using foreach loop. How do list out all information using foreach?

```
echo "".$arr['info']['classes'][0]['points']." ".$arr['info']['classes'][0]['name']."<br/>";
echo "".$arr['info']['classes'][1]['points']." ".$arr['info']['classes'][1]['name']."<br/>";
echo "".$arr['info']['classes'][2]['points']." ".$arr['info']['classes'][2]['name']."<br/>";
echo "".$arr['info']['classes'][3]['points']." ".$arr['info']['classes'][3]['name']."<br/>";
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see the foreach you are currently using,  (I know it's been answered) but that is an important piece of info that was not included.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Sorry, I didn't get it

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix It was/is there at the bottom of the first code block

Comment: Opps, sorry didn't see the scroll.  My bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should foreach your array key

```
foreach($arr['info']['classes'] as $k=>$v)
{
   echo $v['points']." " . $v['name']."<br>";
}
```